# explain the case when v < 0

Tags: c, bit-shift, bit

this logic gives :-

```
if v < 0 then -1,
else +1

sign = +1 | (v >> (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1))
```

For v >= 0, it's pretty clear,
but in case of negative integer , I am in a fix.

let's take an example for `-1` (1111 1111):-

assumption :- `int` takes two byte

`CHAR_BIT` (no of bits represented by each byte) :- 8

SO after the right shift operation we would have :

```
sign = 0000 0001 | 0000 0001
```

SO how does it comes out to be -1

Comment: Is it C or C++?  Add the language tag.

Comment: does it make a difference?

Comment: It matters because different languages have different rules of bit-manipulation. In general, the language tag is necessary unless the question is explicitly language agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of bit-shift: [logical shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift) and [arithmetic shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift). So assuming `int` is 4 bytes, which one is `(-1) >> 31`?

In C/C++, when the operand is a signed type and has a negative value, the result is implementation-defined.

In practice, on most machines, it's a arithmetic shift, which means `(-1) >> 31` results as `-1`, but technically the result depends on the implementation.